# Cannot open and close tabs in Chrome anymore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**The Problem:**

Several months ago we've added a test for a multiple-tab functionality opening tabs with `CTRL/COMMAND + t` and closing with `CTRL/COMMAND + v` keyboard shortcuts.

Relevant helper functions:

```
this.getControlKey = function () {
    var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
    return isWin ? protractor.Key.CONTROL : protractor.Key.COMMAND;
};

this.openAndSwitchToNewTab = function (url) {
    element(by.tagName("body")).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(this.getControlKey(), "t"));

    // failing, if new tab was not opened
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        expect(handles.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);
    });

    return browser.get(url);
};
```

Recently, it started to fail with a `Expected 1 to be greater than 1` error, which means that a new tab was not opened. And, I've confirmed that both keyboard shortcuts don't work anymore.

Why did it stop opening and closing tabs with shortcuts?

Using the currently latest Protractor 2.1.0 and ChromeDriver 2.15 (also tried with the latest 2.16, no luck).

---

**Thoughts and more information:**

1. At first, I thought it is a Chrome 44 related problem:

   - [Keys.ENTER, Keys.TAB, Keys.SPACE are not working on Chrome 44](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1159)
   - [Input.dispatchKeyEvents handles some keys incorrectly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513768)

   But, using `BrowserStack` I've reproduced the problem on older Chrome versions too.
2. It works in Firefox like a clockwork.
3. I can actually see the chord sent to the `body` element in the logs on `BrowserStack`, but nothing happens in the browser.
4. I can actually make the same code work on Windows. **So, it's probably Mac OS specific.**
5. I've tried to change the way the keys are sent. Here are some of my tries:

   ```
   browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.tagName("body"))).sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(this.getControlKey(), "t")).perform();
   browser.driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(this.getControlKey(), "t"));
   ```
6. Also switched to the beta channel and reproduced the same problem on Chrome 46.
7. As a workaround, to open a tab, I can perform `CTRL/COMMAND + SHIFT + click` on any link inside the application:

   ```
   // open new tab by clicking a logo 
   var logo = element(by.css("a.logo"));
   browser.actions().keyDown(this.getControlKey()).keyDown(protractor.Key.SHIFT).click(logo).keyUp(this.getControlKey()).keyUp(protractor.Key.SHIFT).perform();

   // switch to a new tab
   return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
       return browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]).then(function () {
           return browser.get(url);
       })
   });
   ```

   The problem here is that I still cannot close the tab since `CTRL/COMMAND + w` does not work.
8. It's not only Protractor specific. Here is a snippet of Python code that opens up google.com, put "testing" into the search field and sends `COMMAND + A` to the input box. In Firefox, it behaves as expected - selects the text in the input box, but that does not work in Chrome (Python 2.7, selenium 2.47.1, Chrome 46, chromedriver 2.17):

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.maximize_window()
   driver.get('https://google.com')

   q = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
   q.send_keys("testing")

   ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(q, Keys.COMMAND + "a").perform()
   ```

Comment: did you install a new version of google chrome?
maybe that stopped it working. I know new versions of firefox break selenium testing all the time

Comment: @JoeLloyd locally chrome auto-updates and it is the latest stable 44 now. But, on browserstack, I've experimented with Chrome starting from 38 - the same happens there. Which leads me to think it's probably related to chromedriver, not the chrome itself..

Comment: Have you tested it on other OS? I run Protractor on Win7, but I also run Ubuntu via VMWare to confirm, when a bug happens.

Comment: @DejanToteff yeah, I've tested it on Windows 7 and 8 on browserstack and on Mac locally. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should open an issue, that will not be resolved(as most of them recently)

Comment: Have you tried with Selenium 2.47.1

Comment: @Madhan yeah, just tried. Same problem, thanks.

Comment: For python google example have you tried like this `ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('a').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()` or `Keys.COMMAND`

Comment: @Madhan you know what. I've just realized that it works on BrowserStack on Windows and Chrome 44. So, this is going to be a Mac-specific problem I am afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got much closer to understanding what is going on.

First of all, it appears to be *OS-specific*. My own tests on BrowserStack and Madhan's tests on Sauce Labs proved keyboard shortcuts with CONTROL work in Chrome 44 on Windows.

Here is a quote from the relevant [related open chromedriver bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30):

> This bug is *particularly noticeable on Mac*, because a lot of special
>   key handling is done in render view host view mac, which is above
>   where we are simulating the event.
>
> This leads to some things like ctrl+w doesn't close the window (on
>   windows), command+a does select all on mac, etc. This is unfortunate
>   but is able to be worked around for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested with sauclabs from chromeVersion 38 to 44

And it worked only on 44.v44.0.2403.125 to be precise on saucelabs[Tested on local[44.0.2403.130 m] as well]

And I used [ChromeDriver 2.17](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.17/) and SeleniumWebDriver 2.47.1

I've tried it in `Java` only.Hope it will be the same for `Javascript`

```
public static void doChromeTest(WebDriver driver) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        openTab(driver);
    }
    System.out.println("After Open Tab " + driver.getWindowHandles().size());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        closeTab(driver);
    }
    System.out.println("After Close Tab " + driver.getWindowHandles().size());
    driver.quit();
}

public static void openTab(WebDriver driver) {
//Both will work
   //driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t")).build().perform();
}

public static void closeTab(WebDriver driver) {
//Both will work
    //driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "w"));
    new Actions(driver).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "w")).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the participation. What is the exact Chrome version you see it's working?

Comment: @alecxe 44.0.2403.130 m in local machine and I'm using Selenium WebDriver 2.47.1

Comment: @alecxe and 44.0.2403.125 in sauce labs